# How to do a mixed plot of continuous values with a histogram in plotly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I want to make a mixed plot of continuous values like `Age` or `Fare` with a histogram in plotly.

I've got a histogram without desired continuous line so far as:

```
data['Fare'].iplot(kind='hist', xTitle='count',
                  yTitle='money', title='Fare Distribution')
```

I'd like to get a result like this:

[image]

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying `Age` ***or*** `Fare` it sounds like you're looking for a continuous distribution plot and corresponding histogram for ***one*** variable. If that's the case, the following snippet should do the trick using a Jupyter Notebook:

**Snippet:**

```
#imports
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# qtconsole for debugging
#%qtconsole --style vim 

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()
df = df[['FSZ.WH']]
df.columns = ['Fare']

# Make plotly figure
group_labels = ['distplot']
fig = ff.create_distplot([df['Fare']], group_labels)

# Plot figure
iplot(fig)
```

**Plot:**

[image]

I hope this is what you were looking for.
Don't hesitate to let me know if not!